# No resource identifier found for attribute 'text color' in package 'android' --- When building

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am new and now using Android Studio. I have created single page design using XML but when i run the code using the emulator this message appears:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   C:\Users\MHTAREQ\AndroidStudioProjects\JustJava\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
>   Error:(10) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fontColor' in
>   package 'android' Error:(21) No resource identifier found for
>   attribute 'fontColor' in package 'android'

C:\Users\MHTAREQ\AndroidStudioProjects\JustJava\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml

> Error:(10) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fontColor' in
>   package 'android' Error:(21) No resource identifier found for
>   attribute 'fontColor' in package 'android' Error:Execution failed for
>   task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 1 mins 25.346 secs Information:5 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete output in console

**Here is the XML code:**

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="quantity"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:fontColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zero_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:fontColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="order"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zero_text_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"/>
```

Please help.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Post your XML. What is fontColor there?

Comment: Added XML code above

Comment: Here is the font color: @android:color/black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using android:textColor tag instead of fontColor

Comment: Thank You. It works!
But now new problems appears that is " Package R does not exists"
what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: try cleaning your project and rebuild it from Build menu in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific "fontColor" attribute of TextView, that is why it is giving you that error.

Add

```
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```

and then clean your project and rebuild.